# How to calculate (i.e a formula for) page load time, domContentLoaded time from performance logs?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, performance-testing

I am using Selenium API, with chromeDriver, to get the Performance logs - successfully! 
Just a portion below for example.

```
{ 
      "name":"http://ginsoy.com/",
      "entryType":"navigation",
      "startTime":0,
      "duration":16242.659999988973,
      "initiatorType":"navigation",
      "nextHopProtocol":"http/1.1",
      "workerStart":0,
      "redirectStart":0,
      "redirectEnd":0,
      "fetchStart":2386.3250000867993,
      "domainLookupStart":2388.289999915287,
      "domainLookupEnd":2388.895000098273,
      "connectStart":2388.895000098273,
      "connectEnd":2654.6849999576807,
      "secureConnectionStart":0,
      "requestStart":2654.80999997817,
      "responseStart":4028.944999910891,
      "responseEnd":4340.390000026673,
      "transferSize":18214,
      "encodedBodySize":17458,
      "decodedBodySize":79194,
      "serverTiming":[ 

      ],
      "unloadEventStart":0,
      "unloadEventEnd":0,
      "domInteractive":11488.489999901503,
      "domContentLoadedEventStart":11488.804999971762,
      "domContentLoadedEventEnd":11597.39000000991,
      "domComplete":16240.054999943823,
      "loadEventStart":16240.114999935031,
      "loadEventEnd":16242.659999988973,
      "type":"navigate",
      "redirectCount":0
   },
   { 
      "name":"http://ginsoy.com/wpcontent/plugins/wmzoom/css/style.css?ver=4.4.2",
      "entryType":"resource",
      "startTime":4054.6500000637025,
      "duration":337.7549999859184,
      "initiatorType":"link",
      "nextHopProtocol":"http/1.1",
      "workerStart":0,
      "redirectStart":0,
      "redirectEnd":0,
      "fetchStart":4054.6500000637025,
      "domainLookupStart":4054.6500000637025,
      "domainLookupEnd":4054.6500000637025,
      "connectStart":4054.6500000637025,
      "connectEnd":4054.6500000637025,
      "secureConnectionStart":0,
      "requestStart":4060.2800000924617,
      "responseStart":4362.519999966025,
      "responseEnd":4392.405000049621,
      "transferSize":526,
      "encodedBodySize":168,
      "decodedBodySize":206,
      "serverTiming":[ 

      ]
    }
}
```

I am creating an application using Java that needs to calculate the load time of a page, number of requests, the `DomContentloaded` time and some other factors.

**Question is:**

Which elements to add up to get the load time, `domContentLoad`, or where can I find the guidelines for the formula?

```
- PageLoadTime = 12.4ms
- DomContentLoaded = 9ms
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [`DOMContentLoaded` event description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

> The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

If this is really what you're looking for you can get it by subtracting [`navigationStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/navigationStart) from the [`domContentLoadedEventEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/domContentLoadedEventEnd) like:

```
Object domContentLoaded = driver.executeScript("return(parseInt(window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd)-parseInt(window.performance.timing.navigationStart));")
```

Here is how it looks like for [JMeter's WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Very useful information! though to get the time of an event using direct commands using script is not considered as accurate as from logs, and I am looking for elements operations ( e.g I have logs as shown above in question, now I need to calculate time of each event same as _( domContentLoadedEventEnd - navigationStart )_ using the element of logs that I receive)  but yet don't know that which element to subtract from which to get a load time, etc

Some how If I have misunderstood things, you are to clear me out.
Kindly can you guide me to get be there in some way?

Answer (score 0):

domComplete is what you want.   Just report this w3c measurement.

Comment: Not able to grasp the point out of it, kindly elaborate, what it means to report this w3c measurement?
And this element (domComplete) is present into the logs, 7th element after serverTiming:[]
Please share some insights on this element and other to measure the load time.

Comment: w3c, The world wide web consortium, sets standards for browsers and web servers.   The navigation timing interface for browsers is one of these standards.  Of the nav timing interface, ddomComplete represents the closest available measurement to page load time.  see https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#dom-performancetiming-domcomplete and https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/measure-crp

Comment: I mean what and why to report it to w3c? I have just done editing into the comment, to make you notice that domComplete is available into performance timing logs. Kindly re-view the first comment.

Comment: Report domComplete as your page load time.   This measurement is part of the standard navigation timing interface as defined by the w3c for browser manufacturers.  There is no need to report this to the w3c itself.

Comment: That is meaning full peace of advice, so how do I make sense out of other elements to get the other required things done, e.g how do I present this domComplete as page load time by that i mean where from I get confirmation that this element means page load time according to ... source ? From where I fill up this blank space of source name?

Comment: Please see linkedin sources from the ww3c and Google.   As an alternative, you may also use the Performance tab of Google Chrome Deev tools to denote where certain elements occur visually as a cross reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200619/discussion-between-das-khatri-and-james-pulley).

Comment: Private 1 on 1 consulting is available on a non-free basis.  Plus, the community is not able to take advantage of private conversations

Comment: Speak with your local Business Development Manager for TEKSystems Global Services.  I run the Software Performance Engineering & Test group within TEKGS.   The BDM will reach out to me.